# How to get resource name from resource assignment

Tags: c#, regex, mpxj

I'm using MPXJ to read mpp file. I have a resource assignment string as below:

```
string st = [[Resource Assignment task=Sign contract and update data resource=
X.C. Information Management start=Thu Jun 09 08:00:00 ICT 2014 finish=Thu Jun 05 17:
00:00 ICT 2014 duration=32.0h workContour=null]]
```

I want to get resource name from the above string (**X.C. Information Management**).
Currently, I use the code:

```
st.Split('=')[2].Replace(" start", ""); // return X.C. Information Management<br/>
```

I think use regular expression as well as, howerver, I don't have any ideas to implement it.
Please help me if you can.

Thanks

Comment: Is the information you need always wrapped in `<b></b>` tags? Is that always the *only* place with those tags? Do you need those tags in your output?

Comment: @MattBurland: I've edited the code. The string isn't contain <b> tags. I only need value of resource from the string, ex: X.C. Information Management

Comment: That didn't answer my other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression like this:

```
resource=(.*)\sstart=
```

The information would be in the group not in the matched string:

```
Regex.Match(input, "resource=(.*)\sstart=").Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

*If* the information you want is wrapped in bold tags (`<b>` & `</b>`), and there are no other bold tags in your string, then this regex should work:

```
(?<=<b>).*(?=<\/b>)
```

See [here](http://rubular.com/r/pCxfWJp5HI)

In C#, you could do something like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=<b>).*(?=<\/b>)");
string testString = @"*string st = [[Resource Assignment task=Sign contract and update data resource=<b>X.C. Information Management</b> start=Thu Jun 09 08:00:00 ICT 2014 finish=Thu Jun 05 17:00:00 ICT 2014 duration=32.0h workContour=null]]*";
string text = regex.Match(testString).Value;
```

And `text` will equal `X.C. Information Management`

EDIT: Ok - so the OP removed the `<b>` tags, but the principle is still very much the same. Just replace the `<b>` tags with an appropriate marker that you *know* will come before and after the string you are looking for. For example:

```
(?<=resource=).*(?=start)
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt, but I only need value of resource.

Comment: @lekimthi: That's all it's giving you.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... it looks like the OP has retrieved a Resource instance from MPXJ, and is using the `toString()` method of the instance to look at the data, for example:

```
Project file;
// Some code to read the project

// Retrieve the first resource
Resource resource = file.getResourceByUniqueID(1);
string st = resource.toString();
```

This is not a great idea... the `toString()` method is intended to provide debugging information only.

A better approach would be to call a method to retrieve the name directly:

```
string st = resource.getName();
```

You can find API documentation for MPXJ [here](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) which will give you an idea of the methods available on each object, if you IDE doesn't provide this for you.